# Connect to MongoDB with credentials - Micronaut

Tags: mongodb, micronaut

We are using Micronaut to build a web-app. The app needs credentials to connect to a Managed MongoDB service. I see from [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-mongodb/latest/guide/) that this can be done using `application.xml` properties as given below,

```
mongodb:
    uri: mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/databaseName
```

However, here the credentials are maintained as part of the config properties itself.

In our scenario, the credentials are stored in an encrypted store and this needs to be read before the connection to MongoDB can be established.

Is there a way to inject the credentials during the MongoClient instantiation so that the injected credentials can be used to connect to the Managed MongoDB instance?

We are using the `micronaut-mongo-reactive` client.

Comment: Can you set the username and password as environment variables?

Answer (score 2):

In case if this helps anyone the following approach works !!

Create a new Factory with the `@Replaces` annotation that allows override of the default injection of the MongoClient. In this class read the credentials from encrypted store and then use the same to formulate the Mongo Connection String

```
@Factory
public class MongoClientFactory {

  private static final FluentLogger logger = FluentLogger.forEnclosingClass();

  @Inject EncryptedStoreService encryptedStoreService;

  @Singleton
  @Bean(preDestroy = "close")
  @Replaces(MongoClient.class)
  public MongoClient mongoClient() {

    MongoClient mongoClient = null;
    try {

    // Formulate a ConnectionString based on data read using the encryptedStoreService

      mongoClient = MongoClients.create(connectionString);

    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.atSevere().log("Error occured", e);
    }

    return mongoClient;
  }
 }
```

Love Micronaut !!